# Anyone know about collectTotals() Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2.2, onepage-checkout

I need to know about **collectTotals();** and How to work it in **Magento 2.2**? Have any link about collectTotals please provide to me?

Comment: could you provide more details about question ?

Comment: Asking, Have any tutorial about collectTotals for Learn in Magento 2?